# Automatic layout change

Tags: scripting, settings

I am using Debian with KDE. Please tell me - is there a way to automatically change the language layout to English when the screen is locked? I am not an English-speaking user, but I use passwords in Latin.Perhaps this is solved by some kind of script?

Comment: What is the problem, does it not accept the password?

Comment: The password is accepted, everything is fine with this. The problem is different. For example - I work and write a document in my own language, move away from the computer and it set the lock screen. The layout on this screen remains in my language and I often enter the password incorrectly due to incorrect layout. For this reason, I want the layout when the screen is locked to automatically change to English. Exclusively a matter of convenience, and interest)